# Can fallow deer be used for milk?

Tags: fauna, domestication, farming

Is is possible or easy to milk a fallow deer, is it a quality milk, and can it be turned into cheese?

Comment: If apply tranq the taste might be affected, but still better than terrified doe

Answer (score 6):

Historically, fallow deer have been domesticated for purposes of milking, and there is continued interest in the species to this day for producing boutique dairy products.

While deer are nervous animals, with long-term exposure to and care from humans, it is reasonable to expect that they would be no more difficult to milk than a cow (meaning that they would accept the presence of a familiar human and would allow themselves to be milked), and once accustomed to being milked, in the absence of a fawn, they would likely be no less eager to relieve the pressure and discomfort of full udders at the time that they are regularly milked than cows have been shown to be.

However, unlike a cow, the yields would be lower in both quantity  per day and total number of productive days per year.

Comment: I disagree with "no more difficult than a cow" horses and camels have been domesticated and milked  for a very long time and they are still much harder to milk than cows. thanks to many many generations of selective breeding cows produce milk for much longer than any animal normally would. Cows also give a lot more milk than either of these animals.

Comment: I would add the even horses and camels are easier than fallow deer.  Cowboys with experience catching wild horses tend to get themselves mauled trying to catch wild dear.  This is because a roped dear will attack its captor instead of trying to run away.

Comment: My point is that *it has been done already*, so despite any difficulties, it *is* possible.

Answer (score 6):

Possible yes

Easy no

Very few animals are comfortable being milked, even many domesticated animals that have been milked for hundreds of generations are still difficult to milk. (camels, horses). Can they be milked of course it is just a pain in the ass,  the animals don't like it and [it is more work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S000334720091515X), you will not have factory dairy production with deer.

fallow deer milk composition is [similar](https://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search.do?recordID=IT2007600649) to buffalo and sheep milk, so it may even be healthier than cow milk. It is a better source of [calcium and a worse source of iodine](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0921448815300109).

Any milk can be turned in to cheese, so that is not a problem. Mozzarella is actually water buffalo milk.

Comment: For the sake of the many Americans on this site, you should clarift the word "buffalo", either by giving its scientific name *Bubalus bubalis*, or by calling it a [*water* buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_buffalo). Americans use the word *buffalo* to mean what is called a *bison* elsewhere.